# How to set multiple types in numpy structured array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, dtype

I have the following numpy array:

```
np.array([('2021-08-29', 125), ('2021-09-12', 75), ('2021-09-19', 75),
                       ('2021-11-07', 75), ('2021-12-31', 125)], dtype=('<U10', np.dtype('i')))
```

I want to set the first tuple value to `<10` and the second to a numpy `int`, but when trying to assign the above array to a variable, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: mismatch in size of old and new data-descriptor
```

I wasn't able to find an adequate answer in the numpy documentation. Am I setting the dtypes incorrectly with `dtype=('<U10', np.dtype('i'))`? If so, how could I set them correctly?

Comment: [`dtype=[('Date','U10'), ('count','i4')]`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html)

Comment: that's it, thank you!